# windows phone 7 sms arrival

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

Is there any way that wp7 application in windows phone

can trace the sms arriving to the windows phone

in which wp7 application is installed in?

Comment: What are you asking? Your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: his question makes sense to me, coz even i'm looking for exactly same API to use in my app. And there are people ready to pay for this.

you can never expect user's requirements,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no API for detecting the arrival of SMS messages in Windows Phone 7. You can only send SMS messages via a launcher.